# Creating MySql trigger and setting a variable interrupt with inserting into table

Tags: mysql

I created a trigger like this to define a variable:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tt after insert on adventureworks.test
    for each row 
BEGIN
    set @mytime=+1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

on a table that has the following description:

```
'id', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'testy', 'tinytext', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

Now, what happens is that when I want to insert into this table like this:

```
insert into test values (null, "sa") ;
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Why this is happening? Why setting a variable that apparently should not have any effect on my table columns causes this problem?

Comment: With that insert statement, you also need to specify which columns you are supplying values.

Comment: Also, your trigger is useless. The variable will expire when the trigger completes

Comment: @SloanThrasher, In MySQL, a variable prefixed with `@` has session scope, not statement scope. It will retain its value after the trigger is done.

Comment: @nina_dev, I tested your table and trigger as you describe, and the insert you show works without error. I suggest that the table actually has more columns than you think. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE adventureworks.test` to confirm.